# Struggling to set position on my background image

Tags: html, background-image

i was doing for my project regarding my portfolio. I was started coding for the layout and place some navigation bar, images, headers etc. I was placing the ship image in the content background. But when i place the slideshow in the content, the ship image move to the bottom of the layout. I try to fix by using div tag and set background-image:url so both image won't collide each other but when i try to set background-position, the ship's image position won't move. I really don't know how to fix this problem :(

**CSS**

```
#ship{
         background-image:url(image/ship.png) no repeat;
         // Both background-position and padding won't work
      }

**Home Page**

<div id="content">
   <img src="image/welcome.png">

   <div id="slider"> <---- slideshow
   <a href="#" class="control_next">>></a>
   <a href="#" class="control_prev"><</a>
       <ul>
         <li></li>
          ....
       </ul>  
       </div>

       <div class="slider_option">
       <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox">Autoplay Slider</label>

       <img src="image/ship.png" id="ship"> <---background image
         </div>    
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see it but your url(); has to have quotes around the image path.

Try this instead of the #ship css your trying to use:

```
#content {
   background-image: url("image/ship.png");
   backgorund-size: cover;
}
```

Remove this because it is unnecessary unless it is one of your slideshow images:

```
<img src="image/ship.png" id="ship">
```